# Why does The Dark Lord have a goat's face and limbs in The Chilling Adventures of Sabrina?

Tags: character, the-chilling-adventures-of-sabrina

When Lucifer was outcast from heavens he must have had a normal face and body. How did he end up deformed into a goat-like form in *The Chilling Adventures of Sabrina*?

Comment: I'm not sure what the mythology of this series will be long term, meaning we don't know yet if he ever appeared human, but Lucifer or Satan has strong connection stemming from Edwardian times (neopaganism) with Grecian God Pan, usually depicted as a faun or Satyr https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_(god)

Comment: cool. thanks a lot for that reference @DarthLocke

Comment: What is "normal" for an immortal godly or demi-godly creature?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Normal means a Human like limbs and face.

Comment: I get that, but since we're talking about a being that is not actually human, I'm questioning why a non-human "must have had normal" human features?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet like in most of the mythologies most of the Gods do look like humans. With normal faces and limbs

Comment: Does the show actually identify the goat as the Devil? Otherwise it's probably the deity __[Baphomet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baphomet)__.

Comment: Like Oliver, I came to the same conclusion over some recent events.

Comment: "**most** of the mythologies," "**most** of the Gods," - again, why "***must*** have"?

Comment: We don't have to continue the back and forth, I just wanted to let you know why I'm questioning that exact wording. I do understand that a relatively human form is, at least to western cultures, the most common depiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Christian mythology and theology angels and devils are beings of spirit, not matter.  They don't have physical bodies.  But they can make physical bodies for themselves if they want to interact with humans, for example.  They magically gather particles of matter and assemble them into bodies which may be more like non living robots than biological beings.

It is an artistic convention to depict an ordinary average typical angel as looking like a human with a pair of feathered wings attached to their back.  But many depictions and descriptions of not so ordinary angels and devils make them look like science fictional aliens, and I don't mean the more human looking type like Vulcans and Klingons in *Star Trek*!  No, I mean more like the aliens in *Invaders from Mars* (1953), *The Trollenberg Terror*/*The Crawling Eye* (1958), *The Atomic Submarine* (1959), *It Came From Outer Space* (1953), *Quatermass and the Pit*/*Five million Years to Earth* (1967), or in *Star Trek* episodes like "The Devil in the Dark", "Catspaw", "Specter of the Gun", and "The Tholian Web".

For example, here is a [**link**](https://www.google.com/search?q=ezekiel%27s%20wheel&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ8Z_s3MLeAhXRuVMKHcY7CS4Q_AUIEygB&biw=1924&bih=913) to images of Ezekial's wheel, often supposed to be some sort of angel.

Here is a [**link**](https://horrornews.net/50654/demon-profile-baal/) to an image of the devil Baal.

Here is a [**link**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asmodeus#/media/File:Asmodeus.jpg) to an image of the devil Asmodeus.

In Christian theology Satan or Lucifer was a member of one of the highest orders of angels before he rebelled, and thus is often depicted with six wings.

In Dante's *Inferno* the Devil is gigantic, with six wings, and three heads to eternally gnaw on the three worst sinners with.

In the Book of Revelation:

> Revelation 12:3 describes a vision of a Great Red Dragon with seven heads, ten horns, seven crowns, and a massive tail,[96] an image which is clearly inspired by the vision of the four beasts from the sea in the Book of Daniel[97] and the Leviathan described in various Old Testament passages.[98] The Great Red Dragon knocks "a third of the sun... a third of the moon, and a third of the stars" out the sky[99] and pursues the Woman of the Apocalypse.[99] Revelation 12:7-9 declares: "And war broke out in Heaven. Michael and his angels fought against Dragon. Dragon and his angels fought back, but they were defeated, and there was no longer any place for them in Heaven. Dragon the Great was thrown down, that ancient serpent who is called Devil and Satan, the one deceiving the whole inhabited World - he was thrown down to earth and his angels were thrown down with him."[100] Then a voice booms down from Heaven heralding the defeat of "the Accuser" (ho Kantegor), identifying the Satan of Revelation with the satan of the Old Testament.[101]
>
> <sup>[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satan)</sup>

So if The Devil is depicted as looking like some cute and adorable goat in *The Chilling Adventures of Sabrina* the creators made him look a lot more human than they could have based on Christian theology.

Answer (score 2):

[image: TCAoS]

Possibly because it may be based on the real-life depiction of [Baphomet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baphomet) through the iconography of Eliphas Levi and/or [The Satanic Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Satanic_Temple), as The Satanic Temple are [suing](https://www.npr.org/2018/11/08/665783412/satanists-sue-netflix-warner-bros-for-150m-saying-sabrina-copied-their-statue)  Netflix for copying (and misusing) their statue of Baphomet.

[image: Comparative Levi Statues]

> **Since 1856, the name Baphomet has been associated with a "Sabbatic
>   Goat" image drawn by Eliphas Levi which contains binary elements
>   representing the "sum total of the universe"** (e.g. male and female,
>   good and evil, on and off, etc.). On one hand, Lévi's intention was
>   to symbolize his concept of "the equilibrium of the opposites" that
>   was essential to his magnetistic notion of the Astral Light; on the
>   other hand, the Baphomet represents a tradition that should result in
>   a perfect social order.

Comment: Just to note: We don't actually know where the mythology for the TV series is going and if Satan is going to be an equivalent to Baphomet or if Satan will turn out to be Baphomet and not Satan. Right now "Satan" is set up as pretty basic villain, but the choice in iconography could mean there is something more complicated afoot.

Answer (score 0):

In Islam, if you follow the hadith and the life history of prophet Muhammad (صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ), you will find the explanation that the luficer (a.k.a. iblis in the Qur'an) has a body form and features that look like what you see in the picture.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/94754)

Answer (score -1):

What is "normal" for an angel? (this is rhetorical question).

The mythology is that Lucifer is a fallen star. Fallen star is a star that is upside down. A pentagram. A goat head is animal that can be traced into a pentagram.

The view that the goat is the devil animal derive from Leviticus and Matthew. In the latter they state that on the left there are goats that are cursed and should be banished in place prepared for **devil**  (emphasis mine) and his angels.

Comment: The pentagram association with Lucifer likely comes a lot later when the Church tried to persecute pagan religions. Various types of pentagrams or stars (particularly five pointed stars) show up as the symbols associated with many non-Christian deities. The Christian church (literally) demonized a lot of them. A lot of the "traditional" Satan is actually an eclectic collection of other deities. The goat-human partly comes from the Greek demigod Pan and/or satyrs more generally. It's also from "Baphomet" - an idol the Templar were accused of worshiping although it's likely been warped a lot.